# How to generate public key using private key in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a private key from which I want to generate public key using Python.

This is what I understand:

```
privateKey = "XXXXXXXX"

from Cryptodome.PublicKey import RSA
```

I read that **publickey()** can be used to generate public key, but I'm not sure how to proceed ahead. Can someone help/point to good reference material.

Answer (score 0):

Cutting short to

> I have a private key from which I want to generate public key using Python.

if your private key is called `private_key` then the command
`ssh-keygen -f private_key -y > public_key.pub`

should generate the public key as  `public_key.pub`.
EDIT : Keep in mind that the email ID used to generate the key cannot be recovered using this method.  (Though that should not be a problem I suppose)